# What are the strings passed into the logging filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to figure out what the two strings are that are passed into the logging filter I add using the `AddFilter(LoggerFilterOptions, Func<String,String,LogLevel,Boolean>)` extension method. The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.filterloggingbuilderextensions.addfilter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#microsoft-extensions-logging-filterloggingbuilderextensions-addfilter(microsoft-extensions-logging-loggerfilteroptions-system-func((system-string-system-string-microsoft-extensions-logging-loglevel-system-boolean)))) on this is useless:

> filter
> Func<String,String,LogLevel,Boolean>
> The filter function to apply.

Answer (score 1):

1. The first string is the ILoggerProvider that is receiving the log message.
2. The second string is the logging context that logged the message.

Example:

```cs
builder.Logging.AddFilter((loggerProvider, loggingContext, logLevel) =>
{
    // loggerProvider = "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.ConsoleLoggerProvider"
    // loggingContext = "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host"
    // logLevel = LogLevel.Debug
    return true;
});
```